# How to break while = gets

Tags: ruby, while-loop, interrupt

I want to run this code like this

```
count = Hash.new(0)

while line = gets
  words = line.split
  words.each do |word|
    count[word] += 1
  end
end

count.sort{|a, b|
  a[1] <=> b[1]
}.each do |key, value|
  print "#{key}: #{value}\n"
end
```

but I don't know how to break. And Hitting <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> returns

```
word_count.rb:3:in `gets': Interrupt
from word_count.rb:3:in `gets'
from word_count.rb:3:in `<main>'
```

How can I fix this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>. Is this what you need?

Comment: I didn't know that tricks! This solution is best for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can also trap the signal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> sent to the process:

```
 count = Hash.new(0)
 trap("SIGINT") { 
   count.sort{|a, b|
     a[1] <=> b[1]
   }.each do |key, value|
     print "#{key}: #{value}\n"
   end
   exit!
 }
 while line = gets
   words = line.split
   words.each do |word|
     count[word] += 1
   end
 end
```

Reference to the [documentation of Ruby Signal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Signal.html)

Comment: This answer was what i just wanted. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 0):

```
count = Hash.new(0)

stop_condition = "\n"
until stop_condition == line = gets
  words = line.split
  words.each do |word|
    count[word] += 1
  end
end
```

Of course, you could use a `break if line.chomp.empty?` inside the while loop  But I avoid it, as it really is an infinite loop that you know the condition of which you want to escape from.  This also doesn't exit the program, just the loop.

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>control</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> are strange for users, and I would avoid needing to use those things for non-exceptional events.

Comment: This answer is also collect. I agree most app should not use <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. Thanks!